# How to delete a json dict targeted by the value (Python)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
[
    {
        "server_id": 800602366797021184,
        "command_name": "emoji"
    },
    {
        "server_id": 842860085147074578,
        "command_name": "emoji"
    }
]
```

I want to delete ,

```
{
        "server_id": 842860085147074578,
        "command_name": "emoji"
    }
```

using Python json module... and targeting by the value of server_id that is "842860085147074578"

Answer (score 0):

If you've already parsed the JSON, you can create a list without the offending element by using a list comprehension:

```py
result = [o for o in parsed_json if o['server_id'] != 842860085147074578]
```

If you have a JSON string, parse it, manipulate the object representation and write it back to a string:

```py
import json
parsed_json = json.loads(some_json_string)
result = [o for o in parsed_json if o['server_id'] != 842860085147074578]
result_json = json.dumps(result)
```